# Why is this question not closed as too broad?

Tags: discussion

[Can I skip the first leg of a journey, on a two way flight, on a low cost carrier?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/174552/can-i-skip-the-first-leg-of-a-journey-on-a-two-way-flight-on-a-low-cost-carrie)

I suggested closing it:

> We can't answer a question this broad. Yes, some/most LCCs are selling you point to point tickets but we can't answer for all LCCs.

Answer (score 1):

It is not (yet) closed as not enough people voted to close nor did any of the moderators on TSE close it.

I personally do not think it too broad, there are enough possibilities for a good answer, which can include ways to find out whether the airlines allow it.

But if enough people vote to close I will not re-open.
On TSE we tend to follow our users in this kind of cases.

Comment: Well, then the question is, why are people upvoting this like crazy and why no one is voting to close it? It's _obviously_ too broad. Or I am misunderstanding what the too broad category means... which is why I am asking.